# Is there a Reverse-ForeignKey in django?

Tags: django

Suppose we have the following model,

```
class Child(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='children')
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class User(models.Model):

    pass
```

given a user, we can find his/her children via user.children.all()

Question: How to model the following?

Suppose we have a kids birthday party, and each party has one or more children
Conceptually birthday-party would have a list of children

```
class BirthdayParty(models.Model):

    children = models.ListForeignKey(Child, many=True)
```

But, the best we can do with django is using mtm where a table for relation is created?

```
class BirthdayParty(models.Model):

    children = models.ManyToManyField(parent)
```

Comment: Have you considered how this might work? A many-to-many field is really an entry in a linking table, and a ForeignKey is a column on the model's table itself. Where would the data for your field live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a child can have only one `BirthdayParty` (booked?) at a time, then

```
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='children')
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    birthday_party = models.ForeignKey(BirthdayParty, related_name='children',
         # and probably you want
         blank=True, null=True )
```

If a child can be associated with more than one BirthdayParty at a time, then its a `models.ManyToManyField( BirthdayParty, ...)`

In both cases you can access `BirthdayParty.children.all()` to get the children who are going to that party.

Wondering if I've really understood the question?